# Ideal of ideal needs not to be an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Suppose I is an ideal of a ring R and J is an ideal of I, is there any counter example showing J need not to be an ideal of R? The hint given in the book is to consider polynomial ring with coefficient from a field, thanks

Comment: So which ideals of such a ring have you tried with?

Comment: What do you mean by J being an ideal of I?

Comment: I is considered as a non-unital ring, and J is an ideal of it.

Comment: @LokiClock and $I$-submodule.

Comment: What is the most obvious non-trivial ideal $I$ of $F[x]$?

Comment: @loki clock: since I is an ideal, itself is a Subring, J is a Subring of I such that element if I, denote i, and element of J denote j, satisfies i*j belongs to J

Comment: Thanks Matt and Thomas for the below... I had thought there was an easy trick with even/odd degree principal ideals, but yeah, that doesn't work!

Answer (score 4):

Consider $R=\mathbb Q[x]$, and $I=xR$ be the most obvious ideal of $R$.

Note that we can define $J$ as a subset of $I$ to be an ideal of $I$ if $J$ is a subgroup of $(I,+)$ and $IJ\subseteq J$.  Find a $J$ that is a super-set of $x^2R$ but does not contain all of $I=xR$.

Comment: Very nice :) This uses the coefficients rather than the indeterminate to produce the desired effect. I had it in my head there was a clever way to do it with degrees... can you think of one or am I just dreaming?

Comment: I sort of think of this as a "clever way with degrees." Essentially, the fact that $IJ\subseteq J$ only adds conditions about the higher degrees, so we are stuck with just the "additive subgroup" property in $x\mathbb Q$. @rschwieb

Comment: That's true: that's a good way to look at it.

Comment: Ah, my proof doesn't work for prime fields instead of the rationals, and I quickly came up with the following. Let $F$ be any field, $R=F[x]$ and $I=x^2R$. Then find a $J$ with the property $x^4R\subsetneq J \subsetneq x^2R=I$. I think this might work with $F$ replaced by $\mathbb Z$, too. @rschwieb

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure my original idea worked for $\mathbb Z[x]$, since being an additive subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ is equivalent to being an ideal in $\mathbb Z$. @rschwieb

Comment: For $\Bbb Z$ I had $\Bbb Z x^2+ (2\Bbb Z)x\subsetneq (x)$ in mind.

Comment: $\{ax^4+bx^3+bx^2\}$ in $(x^2)$ does the trick, I think.

Comment: There an even easier solution, @rschwieb, and it has the "degree trick" you were looking for. You need a non-trivial additive subgroup of $x^2\mathbb Z+ x^3\mathbb Z$. Your solution is $(1+x)\mathbb x^2\mathbb Z$, but there is an easier one.

Comment: Thanks... this certainly produced and abundance of memorable examples with a variety of characteristics.

Comment: I didn't find some nice $J$ asked by Thomas Andrews.

Comment: OK! I got it! Interesting example. Thanks Thomas for not replying quickly, so that I had a chance to think, and which clarified my question. [$J_1=\{f(x)$ s.t. $f(0)=0$ and coeff. of $x$ is integer$\}$.]

Comment: @rschwieb Do you have any idea about what's the $J$ ?Is it what Atom mentions in the answer below? But then how is $IJ\subset J$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Take $R := \mathbb Q[x]$, $I := x\, \mathbb Q[x]$ and $J := \{a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n : a_1\in\mathbb Z\}$. Then $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $J$ is an ideal of $I$. But $J$ is not an ideal of $R$.